# Parsing xml for user defined attributes in apache pig

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, apache-pig

I have a requirement to parse an xml and generate columns based on parameters specified by the user to the pig script.

For eg,  consider the following xml

```
<school>
    <students>
        <student>
            <name>test</test>
            <rno>1</rno>
            <rank>3</rank>
        </student>
        <student>
            <name>xyz</test>
            <rno>3</rno>
            <rank>2</rank>
        </student>
    <students>
</school>
```

My requirement is to parse the xml and generate the attributes depending on the field names specified by the user. 
For eg, if the user specifies the field name as ‘name|rno’ , the parser should parse the xml and return a tuple containing name and rno.

I am using XML Loader to parse the xml up to student and then have written a java UDF to parse the student xml.
I tried to define a parameterized constructor in my java UDF class wherein I pass the columns/ attributes to be parsed.
I have then overridden the outputSchema(Schema input) method , in which I fetch the column names and add new field schema.

However this does not work the way expected. Is there any way of getting this done?